# Refer relevant K2 smart objects from different sources in a K2 view

Tags: k2-blackpearl, k2-smartobjects

I have recently started working on K2, so please take me as a starter on this one.

SmartObjects

1) I have a SharePoint Smart Object (SpSo1) which lists all vehicle details i.e. ID, make, model, specs etc.

2) And I have a SQL Server Smart Object (SqlSo1) where I am saving only the vehicle IDs against the ProcessInstance_Id.

View

The View is a Smart Object List View which is linked to SqlSo1. In the Edit Section, it has a picker control which is linked to SpSo1, and some DataLabel controls used to display selected vehicle specs. This View also contains the toolbar buttons i.e. Add, Edit, Delete Save, Refresh which execute their relevant functions using SqlSo1. The View also has a parameter called ProcessInstance_Id.

Working

When the view loads it should retrieve and load in the List Section (picker column) the list of all vehicle IDs from SqlSo1 saved against provided ProcessInstance_Id parameter. Simultaneously, against each vehicle ID loaded, it should also retrieve and load into the DataLabel columns the vehicle specifications from SpSo1 against each vehicle ID loaded.

The Edit Section in the View should allow to pick (in Picker control) and load (in DataLabel controls) vehicles using SpSo1 (which is achieved). **Whereas the List Section should display data of vehicles retrieved from SqlSo1 such that Vehicle IDs retrieved from SqlSo1 and their other spec details retrieved from SpSo1 (*Still to achieve and is the real question here*).**

Please help me in this regard. that would be so kind of you.

Comment: Does anyone has answer to my query please? its been two days and no response yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have been finding difficulty resolving my issue that I raised here exactly a week ago but to the reality of this Forum I have not received even a single response from any of its gurus. and I have suffered at my work due to this.

I know I am quite new to K2 but you guys are gurus, you could have suggested at least something on my query.

Honestly, if StackOverflow is only to edit the posts and not suggest on the actual query then my suggestion to StackOverflow founders/CEOs is "SHUT IT DOWN".

Thank me.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve that, you would need to add additional column to your view and to change it to List Display - where you would in turn change "Display" property of that control to show properties from SharePoint list.